# Need to assign values to temp table by qty values

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two tables

**Table A - Line Items**

```
CONS_KEY | LINE_NO | ITEM_QTY
------------------------------
1084353  | 1       | 3
1084353  | 2       | 1
1084354  | 1       | 2
1084354  | 2       | 1
1084354  | 3       | 2
```

**Table B - Carton Labels**

```
CONS_KEY | LABEL_ID
-----------------------
1084353  | 717EXP00001
1084353  | 717EXP00002
1084353  | 717EXP00003
1084353  | 717EXP00004
1084354  | 718EXP00001
1084354  | 718EXP00002
1084354  | 718EXP00003
1084354  | 718EXP00004
1084354  | 718EXP00005
```

I need to create a temp table and assign the LINE_NO to the LABEL_ID using the ITEM_QTY per LINE_ITEM (and CONS_KEY).

In Table A, the first ITEM_QTY Indicates the first three LABEL_ID's are for LINE_NO = 1, then the next one LABEL_ID is for LINE_NO = 2 (total 4 labels for CONS_KEY = 1084353)

**Temp Table - Expected Result**

```
CONS_KEY | LABEL_ID     | LINE_NO
----------------------------------
1084353  | 717EXP00001  | 1
1084353  | 717EXP00002  | 1
1084353  | 717EXP00003  | 1
1084353  | 717EXP00004  | 2
1084354  | 718EXP00001  | 1
1084354  | 718EXP00002  | 1
1084354  | 718EXP00003  | 2
1084354  | 718EXP00004  | 3
1084354  | 718EXP00005  | 3
```

Trying to avoid using a cursor if possible.
This post gave me an idea how I might be able to do it, but not sure how to adapt it for my requirements - [Need to generate n rows based on a value in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439716/need-to-generate-n-rows-based-on-a-value-in-a-column)

Comment: I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add a couple of tricks here since you have multiple occurrences of the `CONS_KEY` column in both tables, and that's the column you use for joining them.
The first trick is to add `row_number` to table B that will give you a number for each label id per cons_key, and the second one is to add `dense_rank` to the join of table A and the tally table that will give you a number for each row that you use later in the join.

First, create and populate sample tables (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @A AS TABLE
(
    CONS_KEY int,
    LINE_NO int,
    ITEM_QTY int
);

INSERT INTO @A (CONS_KEY, LINE_NO, ITEM_QTY) VALUES
(1084353, 1, 3),
(1084353, 2, 1),
(1084354, 1, 2),
(1084354, 2, 1),
(1084354, 3, 2);

DECLARE @B AS TABLE
(
    CONS_KEY int,
    LABEL_ID varchar(20)
);

INSERT INTO @B (CONS_KEY, LABEL_ID) VALUES
(1084353, '717EXP00001'),
(1084353, '717EXP00002'),
(1084353, '717EXP00003'),
(1084353, '717EXP00004'),
(1084354, '718EXP00001'),
(1084354, '718EXP00002'),
(1084354, '718EXP00003'),
(1084354, '718EXP00004'),
(1084354, '718EXP00005');
```

Then, Much like the answer you've linked to, use a numbers table (in this case, the cte called Tally) - but you also need another cte to add the row_number - that's the cte called B:

```
WITH Tally(n) AS
(
    SELECT TOP (select max(ITEM_QTY) from @A) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY @@SPID) 
    FROM sys.objects 
), A AS
(
SELECT  CONS_KEY, LINE_NO, ITEM_QTY,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY CONS_KEY ORDER BY LINE_NO, N) As DR
FROM @A
JOIN Tally 
    ON ITEM_QTY >= n

), B AS
(
    SELECT CONS_KEY, LABEL_ID,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CONS_KEY ORDER BY LABEL_ID) As RN
    FROM @B
)

SELECT  A.CONS_KEY, LABEL_ID, LINE_NO, ITEM_QTY
FROM A
JOIN B 
    ON A.CONS_KEY = B.CONS_KEY 
    AND A.DR = B.RN 
ORDER BY A.CONS_KEY, LINE_NO, RN
```

Results:

```
CONS_KEY    LABEL_ID        LINE_NO     ITEM_QTY
1084353     717EXP00001     1           3
1084353     717EXP00002     1           3
1084353     717EXP00003     1           3
1084353     717EXP00004     2           1
1084354     718EXP00001     1           2
1084354     718EXP00002     1           2
1084354     718EXP00003     2           1
1084354     718EXP00004     3           2
1084354     718EXP00005     3           2
```

Differences from first version:

1. The tally cte is now improved to only the numbers needed.
2. Added a new cte called `A`, with a `dense_rank` column that gives the same numbering as the `row_number` column in cte `B` (that's what was missing in the original version)
3. Included the `ITEM_QTY` column in the results so that it will be easier to see if the results are correct.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's not quite giving the right result, and this is the same issue I was running into. The full sequence of cartons numbers are not being assigned, EG: 717EXP00004,718EXP00004 and 718EXP00005. The carton labels need to continue in sequence into the next line number.

Comment: I see what you mean. Will try to come up with a better solution.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks that's exactly what I need.

Comment: Glad to help ;-)