# Is it possible to create some GUID NOT ONLY in default clause of a table

Tags: sql-server

I want to generates some GUID with newsequentialid() functions instaed of newid()

```
CREATE TABLE AssetPoints 
(
    Id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
    AssetOwner uniqueidentifier,
    assetValue int, 
    RV rowversion
);  
GO   

declare @i int = 0
while (@i < 10)
begin
    INSERT INTO AssetPoints (AssetOwner, assetValue) VALUES (newsequentialid(), 1000 + @i);
    set @i = @i + 1
end
GO
```

but got the following error:

> The newsequentialid() built-in function can only be used in a DEFAULT expression for a column of type 'uniqueidentifier' in a CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE statement. It cannot be combined with other operators to form a complex scalar expression.

Is it possible to create some GUID in sequential order use `newsequentialid()`? Or use `newsequentialid()` NOT ONLY in default clause of a table?

Comment: No, you ***CANNOT*** use `newsequentialid()` in any other way than in a `DEFAULT` constraint - that's exactly what the error is telling you.

Answer (score 2):

> or used newsequentialid() NOT ONLY in default clause of a table ?

If you want, say, 1000 sequential guids perhaps for a temporary reason, or in a scenario where you don't really have a permanent table to put them in then you can still abide by SQLServer's "only in a column default" insistence by making a table variable with that default, and inserting to it (omitting the guid column so it generates defaults):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(g UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID(), x CHAR(1));
INSERT INTO @t(x) SELECT TOP 1000 'x' FROM some_big_table
SELECT g FROM @t
```

You could then use these 1000 guids for whatever you need.. Perhaps you want to insert them in some table that needs a guid but doesn't generate its own (or generates random ones) etc, so you can do like `INSERT INTO PersonTest SELECT g, 'John', Smith' FROM @t` ...

<sub>There are other methods for generating an arbitrary 1000 rows; I just picked on a simple one here of selecting 1000 rows from some big table with more than 1000 rows. If you don't have a table with more than 1000 rows, look at [other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439716/need-to-generate-n-rows-based-on-a-value-in-a-column)</sub>

Comment: If you wanted to avoid the extra `x` column, you could hack it with `MERGE @t USING Your1000RowsHere ON 1=0 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT DEFAULT VALUES`

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you the problem. You don't define the `NEWSEQUENTIALID()` in the `INSERT`, you define the column with a default value of `NEWSEQUENTIALID()`.

This is also noted in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newsequentialid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks):

> NEWSEQUENTIALID() can only be used with DEFAULT constraints on table columns of type uniqueidentifier.
>
> ...
>
> NEWSEQUENTIALID cannot be referenced in queries.

What you should be doing, is something like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.AssetPoints (Id int IDENTITY(1, 1)
                                  CONSTRAINT PK_AssetPoints PRIMARY KEY, --Always name your constraints
                              AssetOwner uniqueidentifier
                                  CONSTRAINT DF_AssetOwner --Always name your constraints
                                      DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID(),
                              assetValue int,
                              RV rowversion);
GO


INSERT INTO dbo.AssetPoints (assetValue)
VALUES (1000),
       (1001),
       (1002);
GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.AssetPoints;
GO
```